# Why can't I enter Jorrvaskr after the battle for whiterun?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't enter Jorrvaskr after the battle for whiterun storm cloak quest, it says I need a key to enter. I finished the quest so why is it still locked?

I am playing on an Xbox one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known [bug](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Jorrvaskr):

> If Jorrvaskr is locked and needs a key, it can be returned to its normal state by reloading to previous save where it should be unlocked.